# Оптимизация функции и apply для поиска массива значений в массиве строк значений по критериям

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, оптимизация, numpy

Как можно повысить производительность нижеприведенной функции?

Функция ищет строки DataFrame, которые удовлетворяют условиям:

1) **Любые** четыре из шести элементов строки должны соотвествовать требованиям

```
второй элемент = первый элемент + 1
третий элемент = первый элемент + 6
четвертый элемент = первый элемент + 7
```

2) Выбранные элементы могут распологаться в строке в любом порядке.

Кол-во строк в массиве порядка 100000000

--

```
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np 
import itertools as itr

df = pd.DataFrame([[1,2,3,7,8,9],[5,6,7,8,9,10],[2,4,5,7,10,11]] * 1)
print(df)

def func(row, cl, sl):
    for i in range(0, cl):
        if((row.values[i] + 1 in row.values) and (row.values[i] + sl in row.values) and (row.values[i] + sl + 1 in row.values)):
            return True
    return False

mask = df.apply(lambda x: func(x, 6, 6) , axis = 1)
print(mask)
```

Исходные данные

```
   0  1  2  3   4   5
0  1  2  3  7   8   9
1  5  6  7  8   9  10
2  2  4  5  7  10  11
```

Результат

```
0     True
1    False
2     True
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

можно динамически создать запрос и воспользоваться методом [DataFrame.query(...)](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.query.html) или [DataFrame.eval(...)](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.eval.html):

```
def gen_rules(cols, nums=[1,6,7]):
    conditions = []
    for c in cols:
        tmp = []
        for n in nums:
            tmp2 = []
            for cc in cols:
                # if cc == c:
                #     continue
                tmp2.append(f"{c}+{n}=={cc}")
            tmp.append(f"({' | '.join(tmp2)})")
        conditions.append(f"({' & '.join(tmp)})")
    return " | ".join(conditions)

df = df.add_prefix("c")

cols = df.columns.to_list()

qry = gen_rules(cols, nums=[1,6,7])
```

исходный DF с переименованными столбцами:

```
In [43]: df
Out[43]:
   c0  c1  c2  c3  c4  c5
0   1   2   3   7   8   9
1   5   6   7   8   9  10
2   2   4   5   7  10  11
```

получим запрос с условиями:

```
In [132]: print(qry.replace(")) | ((", "))\n\n| ((").replace(") & (", ")\n& ("))
((c0+1==c0 | c0+1==c1 | c0+1==c2 | c0+1==c3 | c0+1==c4 | c0+1==c5)
& (c0+6==c0 | c0+6==c1 | c0+6==c2 | c0+6==c3 | c0+6==c4 | c0+6==c5)
& (c0+7==c0 | c0+7==c1 | c0+7==c2 | c0+7==c3 | c0+7==c4 | c0+7==c5))

| ((c1+1==c0 | c1+1==c1 | c1+1==c2 | c1+1==c3 | c1+1==c4 | c1+1==c5)
& (c1+6==c0 | c1+6==c1 | c1+6==c2 | c1+6==c3 | c1+6==c4 | c1+6==c5)
& (c1+7==c0 | c1+7==c1 | c1+7==c2 | c1+7==c3 | c1+7==c4 | c1+7==c5))

| ((c2+1==c0 | c2+1==c1 | c2+1==c2 | c2+1==c3 | c2+1==c4 | c2+1==c5)
& (c2+6==c0 | c2+6==c1 | c2+6==c2 | c2+6==c3 | c2+6==c4 | c2+6==c5)
& (c2+7==c0 | c2+7==c1 | c2+7==c2 | c2+7==c3 | c2+7==c4 | c2+7==c5))

| ((c3+1==c0 | c3+1==c1 | c3+1==c2 | c3+1==c3 | c3+1==c4 | c3+1==c5)
& (c3+6==c0 | c3+6==c1 | c3+6==c2 | c3+6==c3 | c3+6==c4 | c3+6==c5)
& (c3+7==c0 | c3+7==c1 | c3+7==c2 | c3+7==c3 | c3+7==c4 | c3+7==c5))

| ((c4+1==c0 | c4+1==c1 | c4+1==c2 | c4+1==c3 | c4+1==c4 | c4+1==c5)
& (c4+6==c0 | c4+6==c1 | c4+6==c2 | c4+6==c3 | c4+6==c4 | c4+6==c5)
& (c4+7==c0 | c4+7==c1 | c4+7==c2 | c4+7==c3 | c4+7==c4 | c4+7==c5))

| ((c5+1==c0 | c5+1==c1 | c5+1==c2 | c5+1==c3 | c5+1==c4 | c5+1==c5)
& (c5+6==c0 | c5+6==c1 | c5+6==c2 | c5+6==c3 | c5+6==c4 | c5+6==c5)
& (c5+7==c0 | c5+7==c1 | c5+7==c2 | c5+7==c3 | c5+7==c4 | c5+7==c5))
```

**результат:**

```
In [133]: df.query(qry)
Out[133]:
   c0  c1  c2  c3  c4  c5
0   1   2   3   7   8   9
2   2   4   5   7  10  11
```

в виде булевой маски:

```
In [134]: df.eval(qry)
Out[134]:
0     True
1    False
2     True
dtype: bool
```

---

**замеры времени выполнения для 1_947_792 строк:**

```
In [136]: df = pd.DataFrame(list(combinations(range(1, 37), 6))).add_prefix("c")

In [137]: df.shape
Out[137]: (1947792, 6)

In [138]: df.eval(qry).sum()
Out[138]: 14333

In [139]: %timeit mask = df.eval(qry)
134 ms ± 2.08 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

ваша версия:

```
In [140]: %timeit mask = df.apply(lambda x: func(x, 6, 6) , axis = 1)
2min 55s ± 513 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

**ускорение - приблизительно в 1306 раз:**

```
In [141]: (2*60 + 55) * 1000 / 134
Out[141]: 1305.9701492537313
```

Comment: Идею понял. Производительность хорошая, но почему-то скрипт выдает больше записей чем требуется.  Я генерю записи -  iter.combinations(range(1, 37), 6) - из 1933459 под это условие подходит только 14333 записей. В твоем варианте несколько сот тысяч